# FIQ interrupt configuration

Tags: kernel, interrupts

I have tried to write a driver (in the kernel) that interrupts every time the data received from the ADC is ready to be read (Analog to digital conversion is done).
The problem is that sometimes the interrupts are not triggered, I guess because it interferes with other interrupts.
I want to configure the ELC (End of Last Conversion) interrupt request to be FIQ to solve this problem. 
I searched for days the internet but couldn't find a solution to how to configure an interrupt to be FIQ.

This post is the closest topic I have found that can help me find out how to configure an interrupt to be FIQ - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194264/bcm2708-rpi-rasbpian-fiq-not-triggered.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in this article: https://bootlin.com/blog/fiq-handlers-in-the-arm-linux-kernel/

It shows how to implement FIQ for another ARM hardware. If I understand correctly, FIQ is not managed by Linux and needs to be done in Assembler. Thus, a kernel module would need to be hardware-dependent, set the appropriate registers of the device, and implement the call to more manageable (C / C++) code.